# Spring + Neo4J, TransientException brokes connection for the thread

Tags: spring, multithreading, neo4j, locking, spring-jdbc

I have Spring-boot application which updates Neo4J database using several threads created by ExecutorService. Because of multithreading, I have locks sometimes which are not problem by theirselves. But each lock generates `TransientException` and when I handle this exception and the thread receives new data to process, any subsequent write operation produces org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException which says what *Cannot run more statements in this transaction because it's already commited*. Spring transaction is definitely new so it looks like Neo4J JDBC driver broke connection associated with the thread. And calling `transactionManager.getTransaction(trxDefinition)` doesn't start Neo4J transaction actually. How is it possible to handle this? Version of neo4j-jdbc-bolt is `3.4.0`, **autocommit** is disabled by setting *spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false*. Piece of my code is below:

```
public Node convert(TraversalHandler<ConvertTraversalAttributes> converter, ConvertTraversalAttributes attributes) {
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

        return transactionTemplate.execute((trxStatus) -> converter.handle(attributes));
    }
```

The error what I have:

```
com.blueplanet.inventory.neo4j.api.api.ApiException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [

                with ? as input
                call com.company.inventory.createActivity(input.copyFromId, input.properties) yield node
                return node

        ]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Cannot run more statements in this transaction, it has been committed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Cannot run more statements in this transaction, it has been committed
```

`createActivity` call is the first DB modification call inside the `converter.handle` invocation.

Comment: Can you share the code that instantiates the JDBC driver please?

Comment: It's Spring Boot app, Spring Boot version is 2.2.4. I don't instantiate the driver directly, just use Spring infrastructure.
`    @Bean(name = {"dataSource_neo4j", "dataSource_jdbc_DonRiverCoreGUI"})
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource_neo4j() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
`

Comment: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.neo4j.jdbc.bolt.BoltDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:neo4j:bolt://<host>:7687
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:neo4j:bolt://<host>:7687
spring.datasource.username=<user>
spring.datasource.password=<password>

Comment: Could it be that the JDBC connection auto-commit is not disabled? (It is enabled by default).

Comment: Configuring autocommit by URI is a feature that has not been released yet (at the time of writing this comment): https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/pull/265

Comment: I updated my config to turn off autocommit (updated the question's description). But still getting this error.

Comment: Could you share a minimal workable repository? That seems the only viable way forward to debug the problem.